# Google Vision API for django based website

Tags: python, django, web, vision-api

I've developed a website for uploading and downloading images using Django. I've also written a python code using the Google Vision API and executed the file successfully on the command line. Now, where should I place that python code in my Django project, so that my images pass through the API?

Comment: add https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ and create an endpoint (ApiView or ViewSet) to run your vision api

Comment: Thank you. Is the endpoint written in views.py?